# Apply mapping to matrix columns in R

Tags: r, mapping

How can I apply the mapping

x′ = ax + by and y′ = cx + dy

in R to a matrix with 2 columns x and y of numbers, knowing the values of a, b, c, d?

Comment: Hi! Can you show us what you have tried and can you post a reproducible example? Also this can help you: https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html

Comment: You can do `a*df$x+b*df$y` using vectorisation, similar for y', where df is a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Each column `x` and `y` are vectors so you can do :

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
d <- 4
df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 4:1)
xx <- a*df$x + b*df$y
yy <- c*df$x + d*df$y
xx
> 9 8 7 6
yy
> 19 18 17 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is matrix multiplication using `%*%`.

Using Clemsang's data:

```
mat <- as.matrix(data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 4:1))
A <- matrix(c(1:4), nrow = 2)

mat %*% A
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    9   19
#[2,]    8   18
#[3,]    7   17
#[4,]    6   16
```

The columns correspond to `x'` and `y'`.